# Merge groups of consecutive rows in T-SQL and sum values from each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands, azure-synapse

Updated 10/08/2019:

@Gordon Linoff: I have tried to applied your solution but I realized that is not working as expected. I have added an example with expected result with comments here (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1b486476d6aeab25997f25e66ee455e9) and I would be grateful if you could help me.

--

I have a table of transactions with schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions (Id int IDENTITY, SessionId int, TransactionType varchar(50), DateTimeEnd datetime, DateStart datetime, Rank int);
```

Here are some row examples:

```
INSERT INTO Transactions (Id, SessionId, TransactionType, DateTimeEnd, DateStart, Rank)
VALUES
 (1, 1, 'Deposit',    '2017-01-20T11:16:33Z', '2017-01-20T11:16:33Z', 600),
 (2, 1, 'Withdrawal', '2017-01-21T11:16:33Z', '2017-01-20T11:16:33Z', 100),
 (3, 2, 'Deposit',    '2017-02-23T11:16:33Z', '2017-02-23T11:16:33Z', 500),
 (4, 1, 'Withdrawal', '2017-01-24T11:16:33Z', '2017-01-21T11:16:33Z', 150),
 (5, 1, 'Withdrawal', '2017-01-26T11:16:33Z', '2017-01-24T11:16:33Z', 150),
 (6, 2, 'Withdrawal', '2017-02-27T11:16:33Z', '2017-02-23T11:16:33Z', 200),
 (7, 1, 'Withdrawal', '2017-01-28T11:16:33Z', '2017-01-26T11:16:33Z', 10),
 (8, 1, 'Withdrawal', '2017-01-30T11:16:33Z', '2017-01-28T11:16:33Z', 10),
 (9, 1, 'Withdrawal', '2017-01-31T11:16:33Z', '2017-01-30T11:16:33Z', 10);
```

What I want is a T-SQL query to merge groups of consecutive rows by SessionId, TransactionType and from each group to keep only the row with the minimum DateTimeEnd. Also, the Rank value of the row kept has to be the sum of Rank values from the rows of the group. The T-SQL query needs to run in MS SQL Server in Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Desired Result:

```
|    Id    |     SessionId    | Transaction |       DateTimeEnd  |      DateStart     |   Rank  |
|----------|------------------|-------------|--------------------|--------------------|---------|
|    1     |         1        |      Deposit|2017-01-20T11:16:33Z|2017-01-20T11:16:33Z|   600   |
|    2     |         1        |   Withdrawal|2017-01-21T11:16:33Z|2017-01-20T11:16:33Z|   100   |
|  4       |         1        |   Withdrawal|2017-01-24T11:16:33Z|2017-01-21T11:16:33Z|   300   |
|  7       |         1        |   Withdrawal|2017-01-28T11:16:33Z|2017-01-26T11:16:33Z|    30   |
|    3     |         2        |      Deposit|2017-02-23T11:16:33Z|2017-02-23T11:16:33Z|   500   |
|    6     |         2        |   Withdrawal|2017-02-27T11:16:33Z|2017-02-23T11:16:33Z|   200   |
```

I have tried so many approaches and couldn't implement it.

Comment: Actually, I am accessing the database through Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.9999.0. However, I do not know the version of the underlying MS SQL Server. Also, I am connecting to it with Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server through python.

Comment: `SELECT @@VERSION` will show you. If it's an Azure SQL Server, it should be the latest release version (2017 latest CU iirc).

Comment: Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.9999.0 Aug 16 2019 21:18:18 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

Comment: Oh my bad, you did say Azure Data Warehouse. So what do you mean by "consecutive rows"? Just all rows with the same SessionId? Or you mean sequentially by one of the date fields? Can you add the expected results to your post?

Comment: Why rows with `id` 4 and 7 are in the output? If I follow you logic, I think they should not be there, since row with `id` 2 has the same `SessionId` and `Transaction` and an earlier `DateTimeEnd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, as GMB points out.  Because you want to keep the first row, I'm going to suggest a `lag()` approach instead of the difference of row numbers:

```
SELECT SessionId, TransactionType, DateTimeEnd,DateStart, sumRank
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             SUM(Rank) OVER (PARTITION BY SessionId, TransactionType, grp) as sumRank
      FROM (SELECT t.*,
                   SUM(CASE WHEN prev_st_id = prev_id THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY id) as grp
            FROM (SELECT t.*,
                         LAG(id) OVER (PARTITION BY SessionId, TransactionType ORDER BY id) as prev_st_id,
                         LAG(id) OVER (PARTITION BY SessionId ORDER BY id) as prev_id
                  FROM Transactions t
                 ) t
           ) t
     ) t
WHERE prev_st_id <> prev_id OR prev_st_id IS NULL;
```

What does this do?

- Innermost subquery calculates the lag of the id both overall and by session/transaction type.  This uses `id` because it seems more stable than date/times (there are duplicate date/time values in one of the columns).
- When the ids are different, then a new island is identified.  The cumulative sum identifies the groups.
- This `grp` is then used to calculate values over the entire group, using window functions.
- The outer query then just filters down to the first row in each group.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=88b93a7a79d0e0b81fe8dae6b5862346) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I have tried to applied your solution but I realized that is not working as expected.

I have added an example with expected result with comments here (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1b486476d6aeab25997f25e66ee455e9) and I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: @EfstathiosChatzikyriakidis . . . I think because one of the window functions in the innermost subquery was missing `PARTITION BY sessionid`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-island variant.

I would approach it as follows:

1. First, identify and merge the groups of records. The following query gives you the minimum `DateTimeEnd` of each group, along with the sum of the rank

   SELECT
   SessionId,
   TransactionType,
   SUM(Rank) SumRank,
   MIN(DateTimeEnd) MinDateTimeEnd
   FROM (
   SELECT
   t.*,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeEnd) rn1,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SessionId, TransactionType ORDER BY DateTimeEnd) rn2
   FROM Transactions t
   ) x
   GROUP BY SessionId, TransactionType, rn1 - rn2

Returns:

```
SessionId | TransactionType | SumRank | MinDateTimeEnd     
--------: | :-------------- | ------: | :------------------
        1 | Deposit         |     600 | 20/01/2017 11:16:33
        1 | Withdrawal      |     430 | 21/01/2017 11:16:33
        2 | Deposit         |     500 | 23/02/2017 11:16:33
        2 | Withdrawal      |     200 | 27/02/2017 11:16:33
```

2. Then, join the result of the above query with the original table to pull out the rest of the columns:

   SELECT
   t.id,
   t.SessionId,
   t.TransactionType,
   t.DateTimeEnd,
   t.DateStart,
   x.SumRank
   FROM Transactions t
   INNER JOIN (
   SELECT
   SessionId,
   TransactionType,
   SUM(Rank) SumRank,
   MIN(DateTimeEnd) MinDateTimeEnd
   FROM (
   SELECT
   t.*,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeEnd) rn1,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SessionId, TransactionType ORDER BY DateTimeEnd) rn2
   FROM Transactions t
   ) x
   GROUP BY SessionId, TransactionType, rn1 - rn2
   ) x
   ON  x.SessionId = t.SessionId
   AND x.TransactionType = t.TransactionType
   AND x.MinDateTimeEnd = t.DateTimeEnd

Yields:

```
id | SessionId | TransactionType | DateTimeEnd         | DateStart           | SumRank
-: | --------: | :-------------- | :------------------ | :------------------ | ------:
 1 |         1 | Deposit         | 20/01/2017 11:16:33 | 20/01/2017 11:16:33 |     600
 2 |         1 | Withdrawal      | 21/01/2017 11:16:33 | 20/01/2017 11:16:33 |     430
 3 |         2 | Deposit         | 23/02/2017 11:16:33 | 23/02/2017 11:16:33 |     500
 6 |         2 | Withdrawal      | 27/02/2017 11:16:33 | 23/02/2017 11:16:33 |     200
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c1eacb728db562f165b868c241922a10)**

Note: as commented, I think that there is a glitch in the expected results that you are showing. Rows with `id`s `4` and `7` should not appear in the output, since row with id `2` has the same `SessionId` and `TransactionType` and an earlier `DateTimeEnd`.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the implementation approach. I have tried something similar but it is not 100% correct. I do not want to group by SessionId and TransactionType because this returns unique lines per SessionId and TransactionType. Instead, I want to merge **only the consecutive** rows with same SessionId and TransactionType. You can see that in the **desired output** there are two rows 4, 7 which came from the merging of : (4, 5) and (7, 8, 9). We kept 4 and 7 because these have the minimum DateTimeEnd in their groups and also the sums of Rank is 300 for 4 and 30 for 7.